# function is taking Null value by ajax in mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

This ajax is calling from .cshtml file to controller but getValue function is taking Null value on load, but afterwards it works fine. It evens shows the value on alert on ajax call, but getting null on controller. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```js
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
   //get value from dropdown list
    var ID = $('#cmb').val();  
   // ID is taking value        
                $.ajax({
                    // /ControllerName/FunctionName
                    // /Home/getvalue
                    url: "/Home/getValue",   
                    type: "POST",
                    // ID is getting from dropdownList  
                    // parameterName/value                                                        
                    data: JSON.stringify({'_ID':ID}),
                    dataType: "json",
                    traditional: true,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.status == "success") { 
                           //if got response                       
                           //alert(data.status);
                        } 
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        //if if not response
                        //alert('something went wrong');
                    }
                });
       });
</script>
```

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult getValue(string _ID)
 {
     string a = _ID;
 }
```

Comment: data :  '{"_ID": ' + '"' + ID + '"}'

Comment: possible you don't have value in ID. or try to use: data:{_ID : ID}

Answer (score 0):

It is reasonable that you are taking null on the load, since the value of HTML element with id cmd would be undefined, since I assume that there isn't any value that is selected (option of a select element has an attribute called selected, when you have selected a value this attribute has the value true).

The strange thing is that you say that afterwards works as it is expected. I doubt this, except if you have any other code that you haven't include it in your post. As it seems there is only an AJAX call after the successfull load of the DOM.

Usually we register to an event, when we make an AJAX call like this. I could assume that you could register to the onChange event of the value of select element (dropdown)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cmb").on("change", function(){
        //get value from dropdown list
        var ID = $(this).val();  
        // ID is taking value        
        $.ajax({
            // /ControllerName/FunctionName
            // /Home/getvalue
            url: "/Home/getValue",   
            type: "POST",
            // ID is getting from dropdownList  
            // parameterName/value                                                        
            data: JSON.stringify({'_ID':ID}),
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status == "success") { 
                    //if got response                       
                    //alert(data.status);
                } 
            },
            error: function () {
                //if if not response
                //alert('something went wrong');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your URL and parameter check below code for that :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //get value from dropdown list
    var ID = $('#cmb').val();  
    // ID is taking value      
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/getValue?_ID=" + ID,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == "success") { 
                //if got response                       
                //alert(data.status);
            } 
        },
        error: function () {
            //if if not response
            //alert('something went wrong');
        }
    });

});
```

**Cheers !!**

Answer (score 0):

```
Change Paramaters Name 
use id in replace of _ID

[HttpPost]
 public JsonResult getValue(string id)
 {
     string a = id;
 }
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cmb").on("change", function(){
        //get value from dropdown list
        var id= $(this).val();  
        // ID is taking value        
        $.ajax({
            // /ControllerName/FunctionName
            // /Home/getvalue
            url: "/Home/getValue",   
            type: "POST",
            // ID is getting from dropdownList  
            // parameterName/value                                                        
            data: JSON.stringify({'id':ID}),
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status == "success") { 
                    //if got response                       
                    //alert(data.status);
                } 
            },
            error: function () {
                //if if not response
                //alert('something went wrong');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that your ID is not null then just try this.

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
var ID = $('#cmb').val();       
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/getValue",   
                type: "POST",                                                     
                data: {_ID:ID},
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status == "success") { 
                       //if got response                       
                       //alert(data.status);
                    } 
                },
                error: function () {
                    //if if not response
                    //alert('something went wrong');
                }
            });
   });
```